# React Native establecer color de fondo por ID

Tags: react-native

Lo que quiero es que todas las cartas que salen quiero cambiarle el color de fondo, pero cuando presiono otra tarjeta se quita el color de la otra.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    presente:'#fff',
    ausente:'',
    id:''
  };
}

cambiarEstilos(id, ausente){
    this.setState({ausente:ausente})
    this.setState({id:id})
  }

render(){

  return(
<View>
       { contenidosCartas[0].Cartas.Datos.map(

  (item, key)=>{


  return(

          <TouchableNativeFeedback key={item.Id} onPress={()=>this.cambiarEstilos(item.Id, item.Ausente)}>

             <View style={[estilos.cardUser,{backgroundColor:this.state.id==item.Id?item.Ausente:null}]} key={item.Id} >

                  <Thumbnail square source={{uri: item.Foto}} style={estilos.iconUsers} resizeMode="contain"/>

                    <Body style={{alignItems:'flex-start',paddingLeft:dimenciones.width/50}}>

                      <Text style={estilos.txtTituloUser}>{item.Nombre}  </Text>

                      <Text style={estilos.txtInfoUser}>{item.Matricula}</Text>

                    </Body>

             </View>

          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    ) }

)}

)
}
</View>
```

Comment: hola :D podrías ser mas especifico y si puedes un ejemplo para ayudarte mejor, pero presiento que es la forma en que siempre seteas el id de la que acabas seleccionar y no guardas los anteriores

Comment: @KacosPro ya resolvi mi problema, muchas gracias ;)